# Scaffold-DbContext only creates masterContext and nothing else

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I followed the step by step tutorial for Asp.Net Core and Ef Core from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db)

Works fine with localDb but when I try the same on Azure, I only get a partial class "masterContext"

```
  public partial class masterContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            #warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"connectionString");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
```

The command I am running on Nuget is

> Scaffold-DbContext
>   "Server=tcp:dbName.database.windows.net,1433;Persist Security
>   Info=False;User
>   ID=user;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection
>   Timeout=30;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir
>   Entities -force

I have tried the recommended solution of restarting Visual Studio but that didnt do anything. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

**EF Core** is a new product, and still lacks some critical O/RM features.
You can find complete details here - [Features not in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features)

This happened with me when I was trying to create model for table which does not have primary key.

To identify exact error try to run same command again with `-v` option.
This will enable verbose output and you will able to find route cause.

See if this helps.